# What are the advantages and disadvantages of using boost::iterator_facade?

Tags: c++, boost, iterator

Yep -- the title pretty much sums it up. I've got quite a few types that implement iterator concepts, and I'm wondering if it's worthwhile to pull in this boost header instead of implementing things manually.

So far:

**Advantages**

- Well specified
- Less likely to have bugs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If maintaining your own iterator types becomes a burden then switch to boost. They are well specified and tested and less likely to have bugs.

Comment: Okay.. +1 ... but how? The facade is just a frontend that defines the required operators for you on the iterator.

Comment: Can you post one of your iterators with the question how do I do this with boost?

Comment: Sure, there's an example using `iterator_facade` in my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590310/can-i-use-boostmake-shared-with-a-private-constructor

Comment: So, what is remaining of the 'how' part of your question?

Comment: I was asking how `iterator_facade` would reduce the incidence of bugs. At this point I don't think it matters all that much. Here, have +15 rep :)

Answer (score 2):

`boost::iterator_facade` does not really reduce "incidence of bugs". It just simplifies the process of writing a standard conformal iterator. A 100% standard conformal iterator might still have bugs :) With regard to the other question:

> it's worthwhile to pull in this boost
>   header

Yes, it is, if you're  writing iterators of various categories often. This header is quite lightweight, well hm, *relatively* lightweight, since as anything you pull in from boost also brings the gift of mpl and the preprocessor library. I have found, however, that with VC9 or VC10 this is not as bad as it used to be w.r.t compile times...